# Filename string is used without and with @ sign

Tags: ios, objective-c, cfstring

[The iOS SpeakHere example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) has a pair of methods in Class `SpeakHereController`, `stopRecord` and `record` that respectively save and initialize a file for saving the recording. The two methods handle the filename string slightly differently as you can see in the following two lines of code in those methods.

```
recordFilePath = (CFStringRef)[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"recordedFile.caf"];
recorder->StartRecord(CFSTR("recordedFile.caf"));
```

The string `"recordedFile.caf"`  occurs once preceded by an `@` sign and once without.  I am planning on using the following NSString constuct to produce `filename`, but I don't know how to use the result correctly in the two places mentioned in this paragraph. So my question is how to use the constructed string `filename` in those lines?

```
@property int counter;
NSString *filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"recordedFile%d.caf",self.counter];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
recorder->StartRecord(CFSTR([filename UTF8String]));
```

Comment: this is a bad workaround. you can just bridge cast `NSString` to `CFString`

Comment: @BryanChen Why is it so bad? too pricy? Why `(__bridge CFStringRef)filename` is better?

Comment: it perform unnecessary copy. cast is just nop in runtime. (except bridge retained/transfer have an extra retain/release call)

Comment: ... not just an unnecessary copy but given that the storage type within `NSString` is opaque (and probably `unichar`), quite possibly two string conversions. Which means parsing the one format and outputting the other.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is between a C API for string objects (`CFStringRef` in Core Foundation) vs. an Objective-C API for string objects (`NSString` in Cocoa).

The compiler knows that `@"..."` is an Objective-C string literal and constructs a static instance of (a private subclass of) `NSString`.

The compiler doesn't exactly have a similar native knowledge of `CFString` literals. Instead, Apple's headers define the `CFSTR()` preprocessor macro to wrap a C-style string in a Core Foundation string. The argument passed to the macro must be a C string literal (e.g. `"foo"`). The syntax in the other answer which passes a run-time expression returning a non-literal C string pointer not only isn't correct, I don't believe it can compile. Depending on the compiler, `CFSTR()` may produce a true compile-time `CFString` object rather than being a run-time expression.

So: `@"recordedFile.caf"` is an `NSString` literal, `CFSTR("recordedFile.caf")` is a C string literal turned into a `CFStringRef`. You should just think of it as a `CFString` literal.

Happily, Apple designed Core Foundation and Cocoa so that `NSString` and `CFString` are toll-free bridged. They are, at a certain level of abstraction, the same sort of object. You can just type-cast between the two types freely. With ARC, such a type cast requires a bridge that lets ARC know about the memory management of the change.

So, you can do:

```
CFStringRef cfstring = CFSTR("recordedFile.caf");
NSString* nsstring = (__bridge NSString*)cfstring;
```

Or:

```
NSString* nsstring = @"recordedFile.caf";
CFStringRef cfstring = (__bridge CFStringRef)nsstring;
```

For your particular case:

```
recorder->StartRecord((__bridge CFStringRef)filename);
```